# Dir.each paths not working properly in Textmate (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, path, textmate

When I run:

```
Dir.entries('.').each do |i|
    puts i 
end
```

in texmate I get a print out of the parent directory. Why is this?

When I run the same code in IRB, or just from the terminal I get the correct directory.

How can I correct the textmate path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on the default setting of current directory. Let’s say you have a ruby file `/tmp/a.rb` with the content:

```
Dir.entries('.').each do |i|
    puts i 
end
```

Whether you will execute it as:

```
cd ~ && ruby /tmp/a.rb
```

it will print the content of `/user/YOURUSERNAME` since the current directory is the one, the code was executed from. Textmate probably sets it’s own current directory, to where it was executed from or like.

To fix an issue, set the current directory explicitly with [`Dir.chdir`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Dir.html#method-c-chdir).